# "We believe there is a risk of similar legislation gaining support under a Republican sweep."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain that sentence for me, please?

source:http://www.businessinsider.com/why-janet-yellen-could-resign-if-trump-wins-2016-9

Comment: What is it about the sentence that you do not understand?

Comment: "similar legislation", "Republican sweep"

Comment: Legislation means "laws", so laws that resemble the one under discussion. A "sweep" refers to a widespread victory, where all or nearly all of the contested offices are won by politicians of one party, here the Republican party.

Comment: So, does the whole sentence mean: We believe that there is a similar risk of legislation if the Republican party wins?

Comment: Close, but you need to swap "similar" and "risk of". That way you get that it is probabble that laws similar to the ones under discussion will be passed. "similar risk of legislation" would mean that there is a risk of legislation similar to some other risk. Maybe the risks being compared are of there being any legislation under Trump or Hillary, or maybe there is a risk of legislation similar to the risk of the great wall being built.

Comment: Close.  "We believe that there is a risk of (legislation similar to what we discussed earlier) if the Republican party wins."  Similar modifies legislation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“We believe there is a risk of legislation [similar to the one I've been talking about] gaining support [if the Republicans win (or retain) many seats in the coming election].”

In this case "similar legislation" means exactly that, and of course doesn't make any sense out of context.  You'd need to know what the previous legislation was before you can understand what kind of legislation would be *similar* to it.

"To sweep" means to clean a surface, usually with a broom.  The word can be used figuratively in various other contexts.  A "sweep", at least in terms of elections, implies numerous widespread victories.  "The Jayhawks swept the playoffs" means that the sports team won most if not all their games. "In the 1960s radical notions were sweeping the nation," implies that there were many people in many different regions of the country who agreed with and promoted those radical ideas.  "The television series provides a sweeping overview of the political process," means that the series will cover a wide range of topics related to government.  And so on.